# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql

I'm practicing the [affablebean e-commerce tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/design.html), but I'm stuck in a error trying to persist data through mySQL workbench, this is the error I'm getting.

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`affablebean`.`product`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_product_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES
>   `category` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Here I leave a picture of how it looks like (graphically):

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/capturesdx.jpg/]

Answer (score 2):

The error means that whatever value you're trying to insert for the column `category_id` in `product` isn't found in the table `category`, and it needs to be according to the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Dan is right so the workaround this is that you make sure that you

1. Reset both AUTO_INCREMENT to 1 , in both tables (category and
   product).
2. DELETE ALL DATA FROM BOTH TABLES and start over.

and here is the sql statement you need for that

```
set SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
delete from product;
delete from category;
ALTER TABLE category AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE product AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
INSERT INTO `category` (`name`) VALUES ('dairy'),('meats'),('bakery'),('fruit & veg');
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('milk', 1.70, 'semi skimmed (1L)', 1);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('cheese', 2.39, 'mild cheddar (330g)', 1);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('butter', 1.09, 'unsalted (250g)', 1);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('free range eggs', 1.76, 'medium-sized (6 eggs)', 1);

INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('organic meat patties', 2.29, 'rolled in fresh herbs<br>2 patties (250g)', 2);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('parma ham', 3.49, 'matured, organic (70g)', 2);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('chicken leg', 2.59, 'free range (250g)', 2);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('sausages', 3.55, 'reduced fat, pork<br>3 sausages (350g)', 2);

INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('sunflower seed loaf', 1.89, '600g', 3);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('sesame seed bagel', 1.19, '4 bagels', 3);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('pumpkin seed bun', 1.15, '4 buns', 3);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('chocolate cookies', 2.39, 'contain peanuts<br>(3 cookies)', 3);

INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('corn on the cob', 1.59, '2 pieces', 4);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('red currants', 2.49, '150g', 4);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('broccoli', 1.29, '500g', 4);
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, price, description, category_id) VALUES ('seedless watermelon', 1.49, '250g', 4);
```